# SQL Server 2008 SP_OACREATE Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm trying to run following command on SQL Server 2008 DB

```
sp_OACreate 'SQLXMLBulkLoad.SQLXMLBulkload', @object OUT
```

and get below error message

```
-2147221164
Class not registered
```

I have enabled OLE Automation procedures in that server through `sp_configure` SP. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OLE class `SQLXMLBulkLoad.SQLXMLBulkload` is not registered. Make sure SQLXML 4.0 of the appropriate architecture is installed. See [SQLXML 4.0 Not Installed in SQL Server 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2008/05/08/sqlxml-4-0-not-installed-in-sql-server-2008.aspx):

> Prior to SQL Server 2008, SQLXML 4.0 was released with SQL Server and
>   was installed by all SQL Server editions, except in SQL Server
>   Express. Beginning with SQL Server 2008, the latest version of SQLXML
>   is no longer included in SQL Server.

Get it from [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Feature Pack, October 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8824).

Comment: thanks @Remus Rusanu. I installed SQLXML 4.0 and problem got resolved.